# How do I get all the digits of a double in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, double

I want to manipulate a very long number using Ruby. But when I print the number in the screen I get only a few digits out of the original number. So how do I get all the digits I want?

Here is my code

```
x = Array.new
y = Float(0)
for i in (0..100)
  x[i] = 14*2**i
  y += x[i]/100**i
end

puts y
#=> 14.2857142857143
```

Comment: How many do you want? After all, the double you get when you enter `0.1` has a non-terminating decimal expansion.

Comment: Also, you do realize that in floats, there is no difference between `1` and `1+1/10**100`, yes? They are not just displayed identically, they *are* the same number.

Comment: @chris only in `Float`s, but not in arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: It doesn't help to post your code, especially if it does not work. Show your input and expected output.

Comment: Use [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to handle arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: @Jan Obviously. That’s why I wrote “in floats.” The same is also true for variable precision, by the way, just increase the 100 appropriately. Now, arbitrary precision, as in “the software layer will pick enough digits,” has problems just a little step further – how many digits does it take to see that `sqrt(2)*sqrt(3)==sqrt(6)`? (Hint: Infinitely many.) And if you store the expressions exactly (symbolically) instead, you have expression swell and still cannot reliably tell if an expression is zero or not, that is an undecidable problem in a pretty small language.

Comment: What do you mean by "only a few digits"? If you intend to point to `14.2857142857143`, then your English is wrong, and that can be one reason your question is not understood. The English word `few` means two to three, or perhaps four. For five or more, the word "several" is used. But all the digits in `14.2857142857143` still seem to exceed what can normally be expressed as "several".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you get is just a [visual representation of a float number](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/). However internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point) that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.

No matter which code we may provide you, but if a number has infinite representation, every attempt to format or display it in a decimal representation will eventually end with a rouding. It can be 10 digits, 1000 digits, or even 100000000 digits, but it's always a rouding.

Dealing with decimals it's hard. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may want to:

- consider using [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) (BigDecimal provides similar support for very large or very accurate floating point numbers) or
- in case of Money manipulation. you can represent the values as Integers and manipulate integers. Divide the integer by the number of cents just for formatting purpose

Here's an example of using `BigDecimal`

```
require 'bigdecimal'

x = []
y = BigDecimal(0)
for i in (0..100)
  x[i] = 14*2**i
  y += x[i]/100**i
end

puts y
# => 0.14E2

puts y.to_i
# => 14

puts y.to_f
# => 14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do by requiring the standard library `mathn` :

```
require 'mathn'

x = Array.new
y = Float(0)
for i in (0..100)
  x[i] = 14*2**i
  y += x[i]/100**i
end
y  # => 14.285714285714285
y.round(7) # => 14.2857143
y.round(9) # => 14.285714286
y.round(13) # => 14.2857142857143
```

Comment: what is the point of `mathn` here ?

Comment: @bsd see here - http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/mathn/rdoc/index.html

Comment: You are not using a single feature of `mathn`

Comment: Yes..I include `mathn`, just to meet the need as OP asked us. mathn lib is for this kind of stuffs.